# Woocomerce - how to add custom HTML widget in admin area? Edit order, edit product views?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I want to add a widget with custom HTML in it, how can I do it?
It has to be placed in 2 places:

1. woocomerce order edit view
2. woocomerce product edit view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The order and product are custom post types. You'll want to use 
`add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'yourfunction' );`

and within *yourfunction*, call wordpress's `add_meta_box();` function.

The 3rd parameter to `add_meta_box()` is the function which outputs HTML. This is where you can output the div mount point for your react app. The `admin_enqueue_scripts` action is where you can enqueue your javascript into the admin dashboard.

If you google for something along the lines of "add meta box to custom post type" you'll find some blogs with examples.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

Got this answer at Facebook group from Brian, sharing it here for future googlers :)